# Returning data from promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to return data of 3 async api calls using `promise.all()`

```
function apiReq1(apiCred){
  const rds = new apiCred.RDS();
  var request = rds.describeDBInstances();
  return request.promise();
}

function getAPIs (apiCred) {
  return Promise.all([apiReq1(apiCred), apiReq2(apiCred), apiReq3(apiCred)]).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0])
    console.log(data[1])
    console.log(data[2])
    return data

    // ideal return
    //myMap.set('bar', data[0])
    //.set('foo', data[1])
    //.set('baz', data[2]);
    //return myMap
  });
}

// Function that is calling getAPIs
function getAll() {
  apiCred = getApiCred()
  page = getAPIs(apiCred)
  console.log(page)
}
```

The console.log prints out the data as expected however I would like to be able to return the `data` object or ideally a new object with all three iterables to whatever calls `getAPIs()`. This is the first time I am trying to use promises and I feel there is a key async concept I am missing here on trying to return the data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just do:

```
function getAPIs (apiCred) {
  return Promise.all([apiReq1(apiCred), apiReq2(apiCred), apiReq3(apiCred)]).then(function(data) {
    return {
        'bar': data[0],
        'foo': data[1],
        'baz': data[2]
    }
  });
}
```

However, this function still returns a promise, so you cant access the result in the caller synchronously.

You need to modify your `getAll` method as follows

```
function getAll() {
  apiCred = getApiCred()
  return getAPIs(apiCred).then(page => {
    console.log(page);
    //DO YOUR THING
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried this however when I get the value returned from `getAPIs` I get `Promise { <pending> }` and not the object returned from the promise

Comment: what did you log when you call it? show your `console.log` statement

Comment: Edited above with how I am calling the function and the console.log statement included

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, see the updated answer